# Javascript date new Date('2020-1-12') does not work in Big Sur

Tags: macos-big-sur

The new Big Sur does not recognise date if you parse it as

```
console.log( new Date("2019-1-12") )
```

Comment: What language/environment is this? I'm on the latest version of Big Sur, and JavaScript on Firefox still parses the original string. Also, while self-answered questions are acceptable here they still need to be in a proper Q&A format, which this doesn't fit.

Comment: I corrected the question, sorry that was my first question on stackoverflow :). The language is javascript @JohnMontgomery

Answer (score -1):

The new Big Sur does not recognise date if you parse it as `new Date("2019-1-12")` but it recognise the date if you parse it as `new Date("2019-01-12")` the so in simple terms month should be `01` instead of `1`

same thing happens with day should be `01` instead of `1`  fixed it now also